# Including a list of symbols with description and page number

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to include in the backmatter a list giving, in order of first occurrence:

math symbol - dotfill - short description - page number

for example

[image]

Here is a minimal example of what works, but yields the wrong result:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{} 

\newlistof{mathsymbols}{msy}{\listexamplename}

\newcommand{\msy}[1]{%

\addcontentsline{msy}{mathsymbols}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$a\in b$ while $c=d$. 

\msy{$\in$ (membership)}

\msy{$=$ (equality)}

\listofmathsymbols 

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is now your problem? Creating the list? The symbol? The page number?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: How to? I found how to have a list with symbol+description, one with symbol+page number (just the usual), but not symbol+description+page number as shown. Tocloft, for instance, invariably ends with dotfill, and I don't know how to push the description flush right.

Comment: It depends on what you have so far. How is for example symbol and page build? Perhaps it is easier to add description there that to create something new. Best would be you add a minimal (not) workig example showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Package `glossaries` can do it for you.

Comment: I tried glossaries, but nothing did what I want (dots, flush right, page number) . Perhaps I should try harder.

Comment: try `\newcommand{\msy}[2]{%
\addtocontents{msy}{\noindent#1\dotfill#2\quad\thepage\par}}`

Comment: @touhami - You want to make that an answer?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am not sure, this is not the best idea, i'll see if I can do better.

Comment: @touhami Found out that \msy must not follow \end{enumerate} (and similar) without \par.

Comment: @touhami Also found out that hyperref does not work with this msy list.

Comment: yes I know, as I said in comment for @JohnKormylo this is not the best idea    I'm working on a (complete) solution (may be in one hour)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution (quick and dirty)

**Edit: user guide** we need to use `\mtsymb[description]{alpha}` first to give the description, this can be do anywhere, later we use `\mtsymb{alpha}` to get the page number but we can also type `\mtsymb[description]{alpha}`

`\mtsymb[description]{alpha}` in preamble save the description only. in the body save the description if not yet, print the symbol and save the page number.

`\mtsymb{alpha}` only in the body print the symbol and save the page number.

we need:
if hyperref not loaded

```
\providecommand\hypertarget[2]{#2}
\providecommand\hyperlink[2]{#2}
```

create and input list

```
\newwrite\mtmathsymb
\immediate\openout\mtmathsymb=\jobname.msy
\newcommand{\listsymbname}{List of symbols}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\listofmathsymbols}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listsymbname
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listsymbname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbname}}%
    \immediate\closeout\mtmathsymb%
    \input{\jobname.msy}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

entries style in the list.

```
\newcommand{\mtsymbolsty}[1]{%
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
\begingroup
\parindent0pt\leavevmode
\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\ensuremath{\csname#1\endcsname}}%
\dotfill\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\csname mtsymdisc#1\endcsname}%
\hbox to \@pnumwidth{\hss\pageref{mtmathlabel#1}}\par%
\endgroup
\penalty\@highpenalty}
```

Complete code (may be edited later)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand\hypertarget[2]{#2}
\providecommand\hyperlink[2]{#2}

\newwrite\mtmathsymb
\immediate\openout\mtmathsymb=\jobname.msy
\newcommand{\listsymbname}{List of symbols}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\listofmathsymbols}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listsymbname
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listsymbname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbname}}%
    \immediate\closeout\mtmathsymb%
    \input{\jobname.msy}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

\newcommand{\mtsymbolsty}[1]{%
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
\begingroup
\parindent0pt\leavevmode
\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\ensuremath{\csname#1\endcsname}}%
\dotfill\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\csname mtsymdisc#1\endcsname}%
\hbox to \@pnumwidth{\hss\pageref{mtmathlabel#1}}\par%
\endgroup
\penalty\@highpenalty}

\newcommand{\Mtsymbolsty}[1]{%
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
\begingroup
\parindent0pt\leavevmode
\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
\dotfill\hyperlink{mtmathlabel#1}{\csname mtsymdisc#1\endcsname}%
\hbox to \@pnumwidth{\hss\pageref{mtmathlabel#1}}\par%
\endgroup
\penalty\@highpenalty}

\newcommand{\mtsymb}[2][]{%
\@ifundefined{mtsymdisc#2}{%  check if symbol already described
\@namedef{mtsymdisc#2}{#1}}{}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname mtsymdisc#2\endcsname\empty\errmessage{no description}\fi%
\ifx\document\@notprerr%   check if preambl--body
\@ifundefined{mtmathsym#2}{%   check first occurrence
\@namedef{mtmathsym#2}{mt}%
\label{mtmathlabel#2}\hypertarget{mtmathlabel#2}{\ensuremath{\csname#2\endcsname}}%
\immediate\write\mtmathsymb{\string\mtsymbolsty{#2}}}{\ensuremath{\csname#2\endcsname}}%
\fi}

\newcommand{\Mtsymb}[2][]{%
\@ifundefined{mtsymdisc#2}{%  check if symbol already described
\@namedef{mtsymdisc#2}{#1}}{}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname mtsymdisc#2\endcsname\empty\errmessage{no description}\fi%
\ifx\document\@notprerr%   check if preambl--body
\@ifundefined{mtmathsym#2}{%   check first occurrence
\@namedef{mtmathsym#2}{mt}%
\label{mtmathlabel#2}\hypertarget{mtmathlabel#2}{\ensuremath{#2}}%
\immediate\write\mtmathsymb{\string\Mtsymbolsty{#2}}}{\ensuremath{#2}}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\mtsymb[description]{alpha} % this only describe symbol (in preambl)
\mtsymb[description beta]{beta}
\mtsymb[description zeta]{zeta}
\Mtsymb[equality]{=}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
test bla bla \mtsymb{alpha}  %  first occurrence use(output) the symbol and add entry to list
and test bla bla \mtsymb{beta}
and test bla bla \mtsymb[description gamma]{gamma} %this uses, describes and add entry 
bla bla  \Mtsymb{=}
\chapter{Bar $\gamma$}

bla bla \mtsymb{gamma} %this only use(output) symbol

and test bla bla  \mtsymb[second description beta]{beta} %this only use symbol

and test bla bla \mtsymb{alpha}

and test bla bla \mtsymb{zeta}

\listofmathsymbols 
\end{document}
```

**Notes** we use commands `\mtsymb{alpha}`, `\mtsymb[description]{alpha}` for symbols like `\alpha`... and  `\Mtsymb{=}`, `\Mtsymb[description]{<}` for symbols like =, <... may be stared version is better.

**Limitation** we can't use `\mtsymb` commands in section like command.

Comment: Each symbol has first to be described in the preamble?

Comment: @ChrisImpens no you can describ anywhere

Comment: Why the descriptions in the preamble then? (Could not add my own examples, that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: @ChrisImpens well, it may be useful. you can check symbol description easy and edit it any time ...

Comment: @ChrisImpens I add some explanation

Comment: Accepting the (common) drawback of not being applicable within section-like environments, could not your first solution be modified so as to replace page number # with \hyperlink{page.#}{#}? (Works fine manually.)

Comment: @ChrisImpens of course there may be another way but 1) it is not so simple 2) there is many check (test if first ocurrence, not described) that need care.